# Webpack: ES6 modules, code splitting, and bundle-loader

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, code-splitting

***TL;DR:*** Could you please explain when `bundle-loader` is needed for code splitting using Webpack?

When I started migrating a Backbone-based app from Require.js to Webpack, I remember that this kind of `require` statement in the router:

```js
someMatchedRoute: function () {
    require(['path-to-file'], function(module) {
        // doing something with the loaded module
        module();
    });
}
```

would put the required code in the same bundle as the rest of the code, and in order to generate a separate file that would be required dynamically when switching to a particular route, I needed to use `bundle-loader`, like so:

```js
// a function executed when the user’s profile route is matched
someMatchedRoute: function () {
    require('bundle!path-to-file')(function(module) {
        // doing something with the loaded module
        module();
    });
}
```

Now, when I am migrating my codebase to ES6 modules and using the `require.ensure` syntax as [described](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#es6-modules) in Webpack documentation:

```js
someMatchedRoute: function () {
    require.ensure(['path-to-file'], function(require) {
        var loadedModule = require('path-to-file');
        // doing something with the loaded module
        loadedModule();
    });
}
```

I am unsure whether I need `bundle-loader` at all to in order to generate multiple chunks and load them dynamically. And if I do, in which `require` call does it go — in the `require.ensure` or in the `require` in the callback? Or maybe both? It's all so confusing.